# Change font color after createElementNS()

Tags: javascript, svg

im building a game and try to display the highscores at the end. The current username should be highlighted with a different color but I can't get it to work.
When I tried to change the fontsize for testing purposes it workes though!

```
var nameSpan = svgdoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");

nameSpan.setAttribute("x", 130);
nameSpan.setAttribute("dy", 30);

var nameTextNode = svgdoc.createTextNode(record.name);

if (record.name == playerName){
    nameSpan.style.fontColor = "red"; // does not work
    nameSpan.style.color = "blue"; // does not work
    nameSpan.style.fontSize = "100px"; // works fine
}

nameSpan.appendChild(nameTextNode);
```

I tried different ways to apply the color(2 of them can be seen above) but it stays black all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG text is not coloured using color. Instead it uses fill and stroke so you can colour the outline separately. Change things to  `nameSpan.style.fill = "blue"` and it should work for you.